# Query + Transpose based on value in Column B if Column A contains certain text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently working with Google Forms and want to rearrange the way the responses are being displayed on the "Response Sheet". The only way I can think of doing this is by importing or moving the data to another sheet that would select and transpose certain columns if Column A contains key value.

This is what I'm seeing as part of the input and would like to see as the output if Column A Contains certain text:

[Input & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Vxv.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are the column names real or just a dummy example (I wonder if I should use 1, 2.1, 3.1 as a key for identifying columns) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K.

1. I rewrite headings a2:e2,
2. I take whole first five columns without headings e3:e6
3. I display content of columns  A,B,F,G,H for all the rows that have 'A1' in column 1
4. I take tables built in point 1 and 2 together and sort them by first column

My solution is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n7Ppd8v75mb3qrnJz_Jh_b4HNaj4i56X9wRGnz0l6i8/copy

```
   ={A2:E2;
    sort({A3:E6;
    query(A3:H6,"select A,B,F,G,H where A ='A1'",0)})
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much Krzysztof... Do you think it'd be possible to combine this with an Array Expression Formula?... I've worked on a Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UC1r1JaO7ghJKJi12oovgzIAwtp1lA6bfsBdvhYmv_o/edit#gid=758899382 that has the From Responses and the Desire Output on Tab 2... wondering if there's anyway I can get to the Desire Output combining your formula and the Array Expression one